# How to tag a single file? or How do I download a specific file? - GIT

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to add a tag to a file to easily download that file and not the entire branch.

How do I download a specific file in GIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to tag specific files in `git`.

---

For the second question: **How do I download a specific file in `git`?**

*The following works only if you mean "download while **in** a `git` repository" (That's how I understand your question, if you mean **with** git without having the repository see [Get a single file from a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642143/get-a-single-file-from-a-remote-git-repository)
 or [Not able to extract single file from remote git server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883740/not-able-to-extract-single-file-from-remote-git-server)
)*

```
$ git checkout tagged-commit -- path/to/file.example
```

Where `tagged-commit` can be a lot of things, among others:

- A commit hash
- A git tag
- A branch name
- For more ways see [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for that. I appreciate it a lot.
regards

Answer (score 2):

The way `git` works is by adding a tag to the entire tree at the state of the commit. There is no way to add a tag to a single file.

Since you are using gitlab, you can just download the file in the right revision from the web interface.

Comment: the problem is that I need something why I am developing a script where I update certain files in specific.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you *can* tag a blob object, but it's not common to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For GitLab specifically, downloading a single file is now explicitly supported, since GitLab 11.2 (August 22nd, 2018), thank to [Kia Mei Somabes](https://gitlab.com/kia1) .

See "[**Download individual repository files**](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/08/22/gitlab-11-2-released/#download-individual-repository-files)":

> When browsing through a project repository on GitLab, the need to download a specific file frequently arises.
> Until now, this was only possible within the GitLab interface by viewing the file in a new browser tab and then saving it.
>
> **GitLab 11.2 introduces a new “`Download`” button in the file viewer interface, available for each individual repository file, allowing you to download any file directly from the application more easily.**

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_2/download-single-files.png]

- [See documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/),
- [see issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23705),
- [see merge-request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/20480).